# Dictating the signs of terms in SymPy's "linear_eq_to_matrix"

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, matrix-multiplication

I'm using SymPy (within a Juptyer Notebook) to do some basic calculations with a system of equations. I am using `sympy.linear_eq_to_matrix` to turn them into matrix form.

I'm trying to use these functions in an educational context, and while the result of `sympy.linear_eq_to_matrix` is correct, it makes atypical choices about what quantities are positive vs. negative.

For example, I am trying to arrive at the matrix equation F = Ku, where F and u are 1 by n vectors, and K is an n by n matrix. Students will typically encounter this equation in symbolic form with all the quantities in F and u appearing as positive terms, while the matrix K carries the appropriate signs to make the equations valid. When I call `sympy.linear_eq_to_matrix`, it will often return F with mixed signs or u with mixed signs. Is it possible to force the terms in F and u to be positive?

For a simple example, you can look at the last two lines of the following notebook:
https://github.com/dpholmes/DirectStiffnessMethod/blob/master/planarBeams.ipynb (FWIW the signs are also "mixed up" in the variable `Lmat` called earlier in the notebook.

Just to reiterate, the solutions are *correct*, just not in the "textbook" form students the students will encounter. This has some potentially practical drawbacks as well, since the students will often provide/enter values of u or F to solve a problem, and the flipped signs will likely be confusing.

Comment: Maybe you could define your equations as `Eq(-lhs, rhs)`, to you get the desired signs.  It seems sympy first rewrites them the old way as an equation equal to zero and then uses these signs.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of SymPy appears to respect the signs:

```
>>> linear_eq_to_matrix(-(L**3*a4+L**2*a3+L*a2+a1),(a1,a2,a3,a4))
(Matrix([[-1, -L, -L**2, -L**3]]), Matrix([[0]]))
>>> linear_eq_to_matrix(L**3*a4+L**2*a3+L*a2+a1,(a1,a2,a3,a4))
(Matrix([[1, L, L**2, L**3]]), Matrix([[0]]))
```

Which version are you using?

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'1.6.dev'
```

Comment: interesting... i'm using 1.4 (although, that is not by choice, i'm happy to use the newer version)